# Remote desktop, does user get control back?

Tags: windows-8, remote-desktop

I'm curious if I log in remotely to a computer and it asks if I still want to log in even if the other user will get logged out will he/she automatically get logged in once I'm done?

Comment: No;  They  will have to log into their account because they logged out to allow you to log into your account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That user is still technically logged in; their running tasks will still continue, but when you close your remote session they will still see the users' login page & have to re-enter credentials to get back into their desktop.

As far as I'm aware there is no real indication of when you left the session.

*This is based on my usual procedure of logging in with that user's credentials & leaving without logging out, by simply closing my current session.*